# Selecting All records From Kendo Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo grid in Visual Studio 2010 Asp.net & C#. Im new to this platform. I have more than 100 records in that grid.. i want to select all the records in an array.. Am using the following code.. It selects only the first page records. (PageSize: 5 )..

```
 var entityGrid = $("#grdReport").data("kendoGrid");
 var d = entityGrid.dataSource.data();                                         
 for(var i = 0; i<d.length; i++) 
 {
     var currentDataItem = d[i];  
   a.push(currentDataItem);
 }  
 appnt = a;
```

appnt has only 5 records.. So please Help me in this issue... Thanks in Advance.. :-) Be happy..

Answer (score 1):

You should use **ServerOperation** of the dataSource sorce set to false if using the MVC wrappers.

If using the regular JavaScript declaration you should set the **[serverPaging](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-serverPaging)** of the dataSource to false.

Answer (score 0):

How do you load them? Are they actually loaded in the browser or are you using Server Paging?

If you have actually the data loaded what you do is correct BUT if the data is actually still in the server, you should check the total using:

```
var entityGrid = $("#grdReport").data("kendoGrid");
console.log("Total length: ", entityGrid.dataSource.total());
```

**BUT** you cannot get the data since it is actually not in the browser, you will get it when moving to a different page.

So the question is: how are you defining the DataSource?

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/td8Ww/